# Make an ArrayList of class C from a List of interface I

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, java-8, java-stream

Considering these elements :

**An interface `I` :**

```
public interface I {
    int getType();
}
```

**A class `C` :**

```
public class C implements I {
    @Override
    public int getType() { return 0; }
}
```

---

Given a list Of `I`, how can I make an ArrayList of `C` using Java 8 ?

**Here is what I tried :**

```
public void foo(List<? extends I> listI) {

    List<C> listC = new ArrayList<>((List<C>)listI.stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getType() == 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

**And the warning I got :**

> Unchecked cast: `'java.util.List<capture<? extends I>>'` to `'java.util.List<C>'`

Comment: `filter(o -> o instanceof C).map(o -> (C) o)`.

Comment: isnt it a bad practice to use instanceof outside of equals functions ?

Comment: `public class C extends I` -- this is not valid Java, a class cannot `extend` an interface.  It can only `implement` an interface.  If you want help you have to start with ***valid*** compilable Java code.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand if you want to check if something is an instance of `C`, how else would you do it?

Comment: What do you do if the `List<I>` contains objects that implement `I` but are not `C` or one of its subclasses? That is why your original attempt does not work.

Comment: @JimGarrison that was a simple typo mistake, thanks for seeing it

Comment: @JimGarrison then listC would simply be empty, right ?

Comment: The moral here is NEVER type code into a SO question, ALWAYS copy/paste to avoid typos.

Comment: @AndyTurner I see, then there it should be fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll first need to perform a `filter` intermediate operation to retain all the objects of type `C` and then a `map` to perform the transformation i.e:

```
List<C> listC = listI.stream().filter(e -> e instanceof C).map(e -> (C) e).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Also, when you perform a collect operation you need not use the `ArrayList` constructor to create a new list rather just use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` and assign that directly to `listC`.

Answer (score 4):

`C.getType()` may return 0, but other implementations  of `I` may do too, so you can't simply check `getType() == 0`.

To get instances of `C`, you've got to filter using `instanceof`:

```
.filter(o -> o instanceof C)
```

which yields a `Stream<? extends I>`; then cast to `C` to get a `Stream<C>`:

```
.map(o -> (C) o)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
List<C> listC = StreamEx.of(listI).select(C.class).toList();
```

It's simple, short and concise to me.

Comment: From an API design perspective, I'm not keen on this. What does "select" mean? Instances of? Exactly the same class as? Equal to? etc. I'd plump for standard APIs and only slightly more verbosity.

Comment: Basically, I agree what you said. I had the similar feeling when I saw the API at first time. But I feel pretty good by using it now after I knew what the API does and used it for several times. Sometimes, accepting it or not really depends on personal experiences .